# How to remove the Sendmail Mail Server from webmin?

Tags: server, services, mail

I mean to remove the  Sendmail Mail Server on webmin, any idea how to remove it? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to remove it *from Webmin*?

Comment: webmin is no longer supported in Debian and Ubuntu.It is not compatible with the way that Ubuntu packages handle configuration files, and is likely to cause unexpected issues with your system.

Comment: @karthick87 What is the Ubuntu equivalent then? I use webmin for basic monitoring, logging, and management at it works just fine

Comment: im using webmin just for my server , do you know anything are the best for managing the server ? as i us till now its work the best ,

Comment: @Olivier Lalonde emmm, that is good, but i don't need its now, just want to make all system going simple , :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Webmin is only a web based interface to various services and applications on Ubuntu, If you have the  Mail Transport Agent (MTA), sendmail, installed and want to remove it then use the apt-get remove sendmail or apt-get purge sendmail command as usual or use the synaptic package manager,  If you mean uninstalling via the webmin interface then you can use the command shell by expanding the others item in the left pane and clicking the command shell item then run the apt-get command from the corresponding page. You may have to use the --yes switch when you run commands from there, it is not recommended at all, it would be best to use ssh for this, an ssh interface is available in webmin but it does not work sometimes.

If you just want to remove  the sendmail module in webmin that interfaces with the sendmail MTA then doing the following may help:

In the side bar click webmin when the items expand click webmin configuration, in the window on right click webmin modules, in the page that appears, click the delete tab, In the Delete modules list box select the required module then click the Delete selected modules button, you may have to click the refresh modules Item at  the bottom of the left pane.

Some people used to recommend ebox (available in the repository) as a replacement for webmin, I do not know how well this will work as I have never used it.

ebox have since become  Zentyal available here; http://www.zentyal.org/   The installation guide is here; http://trac.zentyal.org/wiki/Document/Documentation/InstallationGuide

Comment: i got the way to remove the Sendmail Mail  by myself , i got the configuration its on the webmin that allowing me to drooping / removing the application , thanks for the helping . :D